# Is there a "cubical" version of quasicategories?

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff

Definitions:

- A **Kan complex** is a simplicial set having the horn-filling condition;
- A **quasicategory** is a simplicial set having the inner-horn-filling condition.

My question is:

> I was wondering if there are analogous definitions for cubical sets, giving rise to "cubical" versions of Kan complexes and quasicategories?

(Note: by a simplicial set we mean a Set-valued presheaf on the simplex category, and by a cubical set we mean a Set-valued presheaf on the [cube category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+of+cubes).)

---

Edit: see Zhen Lin’s comment for a reference on cubical Kan complexes.

However, I'm still not sure what would be the appropriate "cubical" version of the *inner* horn condition which defines quasicategories (among simplicial sets). (This is as opposed to the usual horn condition, whose cubical version I think I understand.) Would anyone know how a cubical analogue of the inner horn condition can be approached?

Comment: In fact, cubical Kan complexes were defined first. See [Kan, 1956, _Abstract homotopy. I–IV_]. (The old terminology is different from the modern one, so one has to read all the definitions carefully.)

Comment: @ZhenLin I see, thank you for your explanation and reference suggestion! (However, I am also still wondering about the possibility of a cubical version of quasi categories (as opposed to just Kan complexes).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by googling:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.04853 Cubical models of (∞,1)-categories.
(The authors use additional structure ["connections" or "markings"] to obtain the desired model structure).